# The Problem of Marginalizing Expression (6) in DDIM Papers

Tags: conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I have a question in the process of marginalizing equation (6) in the DDIM paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.02502.pdf).

[image]

When the joint distribution is defined like this (eq(6))

$$
q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_{1:T} \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0) := q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_T \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0) \prod_{t=2}^T q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_{t-1} \mid \boldsymbol{x}_t, \boldsymbol{x}_0) 
$$

Is it possible to show the following?
I think this should be possible according to the argument in the paper.

$$
\int q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_{1:T} \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0) d\boldsymbol{x}_{1:(T-1)} = q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_{T} \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0)
$$

Concretely, if we say $T=3$, then

$$
\int_{\boldsymbol{x}_1} \int_{\boldsymbol{x}_2} q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_3 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0) q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_1 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_2, \boldsymbol{x}_0) q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_2 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_3, \boldsymbol{x}_0) d\boldsymbol{x}_2 d\boldsymbol{x}_1 = q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_{3} \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0) \tag{*}
$$

On the other hand, for the case $t < T$, it is easy to localize it

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{\boldsymbol{x}_1} \int_{\boldsymbol{x}_3} q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_3 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0) q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_1 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_2, \boldsymbol{x}_0) q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_2 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_3, \boldsymbol{x}_0) d\boldsymbol{x}_3 d\boldsymbol{x}_1 \\
&= \int_{\boldsymbol{x}_1} q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_1 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_2, \boldsymbol{x}_0) \int_{\boldsymbol{x}_3}   q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_2 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_3, \boldsymbol{x}_0) q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_3 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0) d\boldsymbol{x}_3 d\boldsymbol{x}_1 \\
&=  \int_{\boldsymbol{x}_1} q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_1 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_2, \boldsymbol{x}_0) q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_2 \mid  \boldsymbol{x}_0) d\boldsymbol{x}_1 \\
&= q_{\sigma}(\boldsymbol{x}_2 \mid \boldsymbol{x}_0)
\end{aligned}
$$

I would appreciate it if you could explain how the (*) is derived.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{x_1} \int_{x_2} q_{\sigma}(x_3 | x_0)q_{\sigma}(x_1 | x_2, x_0) q_{\sigma}(x_2 | x_3, x_0) dx_2 dx_1 &= q_{\sigma}(x_3 | x_0) \int_{x_1} \int_{x_2} q_{\sigma}(x_1 | x_2, x_0) q_{\sigma}(x_2 | x_3, x_0) dx_2 dx_1 \\
&=q_{\sigma}(x_3 | x_0)\int_{x_1} \int_{x_2} q_{\sigma}(x_1 | x_2, x_3, x_0) q_{\sigma}(x_2 | x_3, x_0) dx_2 dx_1 \quad \because x_1 \perp x_3 \\
&=q_{\sigma}(x_3 | x_0) \int_{x_1} \int_{x_2} q_{\sigma}(x_1 , x_2 | x_3, x_0)  dx_2 dx_1 \\
&=q_{\sigma}(x_3 | x_0)
\end{aligned}
$$